# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found: For App Store Distribution Profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I know there are lots of questions regarding this same. But as none of them are not able to solve my issue, i have to post this question.

I build an application and i want to test it in device and submit this application to apple store. So i follow this steps.

```
1. Generate a build identifier (com.x.deviceapp) on developer portal.
2. Generate ios-Distribution certificate (iPhone Distribution: x) on Portal.
3. Generate AppStore-Distribution certificate with bundle_id = com.x.deviceapp and ios-Distribution = iPhone Distribution: x
4. Download Both (ios-Distribution and AppStore-Distribution) Certificate and install them.
5. In my project i change bundle identifier=com.x.deviceapp in info.Plist
6. Try to run application in my Device
```

Now after 6th step it shows me an alert saying that "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found".

Where as there isn't any problem with generating .ipa file. But i am not able to install that ipa file into device.

I repeat this process for 3 times. But same error continues. Even i tried with different bundle id and new project.

However i able to submit my application to apple store

I am using Xcode 5.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make test for apps in device means  use development certificates other wise you can publish apps in App Store  or IPA File make distribution certificates.if you have any doubt refer this [provisioning profile](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)